# Error creating bean unsatisfied dependency expressed through field sessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, exception, javabeans

I am getting below error where it says column does not exist in `SECU` table. But the problem is i really dont need this column in this table as this i only needed this column in `NONSECU` table which is only referenced in `NONSECU` class.

Is there any way to get rid of this in getbean method or elsewhere ?

```
`[main] WARN  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IsmaImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in baag.betl.dbimporter.esmatrans.SpringConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [preTradLrgInScaleThrshld] in table [SECU]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("baag.betl.dbimporter.Ismatr")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration {

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return createDatasource("dwh.");
}

private DriverManagerDataSource createDatasource(String propertyPrefix) {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(propertyPrefix + "driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(propertyPrefix + "jdbc"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(propertyPrefix + "user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(propertyPrefix + "pwd"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.batch.size"));
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.current.session.context.class"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Secu.class, NonSecu.class);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}
```

}

Comment: could you add your entity class pls

Comment: @Andrew Please show your entity class for better understanding

Comment: entity class means where i have created get and set methods for all entites?

Comment: Just show Secu and NonSecu classes.

Comment: added entity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to ignore column-mapping for some field just declares them as `Transient`

Like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECU")
public class SECU implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    protected BigDecimal preTradLrgInScaleThrshld;
```

This field won't be persist and will always have null value post load.

Comment: but will it really avoid error missing column in table ? if i remove the line protected BigDecimal preTradLrgInScaleThrshld;  then it gives me same error

Comment: does the field exists in NonSecu class ?

Comment: yes actually i needed this field only in for NonSecu table so i have added them in Nonsecu class

Comment: I saw `protected` do you have some entity inheritance ? some bean inherited `Secu.class` ?

Comment: so why `protected`? did you try with `@Transient` ?

Comment: i didnt tried with transient because i thought it will throw same error again as the column itself not present in secu table...should i try with this ?

Comment: actually hibernate should ignore transient field so  if error still here the problem is elsewhere